# Do Frozen PyQt applications need the Qt to be installed on client machines

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am new to Qt and developing with python.

Would a python application developed using Qt framework and PyQt require the entire Qt framework to be installed on a user's machine in order to run a "exe" version of the application created with something like p2exe? Or would py2exe copy the required Qt framework components into the application that it creates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for further install. 
e.g. Py2exe will copy everything needed.

If you have some special requirement you may have to copy other stuff manually. In my application I copy some extra ddls, some ico files and some matplotlib files.

Comment: So there is no need to have the Qt framework installed on the user's machine? You only need Qt, PyQt and Python on the developer machine where you develop and then create the exe?

Comment: I'm not so sure that Py2exe knows anything about Qt plugins - how could it know what plugins does the application need? It can't. This plugins don't appear in the executable image. It will appear to "work" with Qt 4, and it plain won't work with Qt 5. Missing plugins in Qt 4 cause loss of functionality, but at least something comes up. Missing plugins in Qt 5 are fatal. In both cases, your app doesn't quite work, since with Qt 4 you lose the image plugins, database driver plugins, etc.

Comment: Well it works for me.  As written if you need additional stuff you need to copy it manually

Comment: By manually I mean, as part of your setup.py script. The user wanted to know if he should install stuff on the client and the answer is no.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by "frozen" but if your question is whether you can create an "exe" for a pyqt python script without installing python and pyqt on user machine then answer is yes. As with any other exe you don't need to install anything on user machine.

I have created a few application using pyqt and converted them to exe using pyinstaller-2.0 and it works fine on any machine. Same is true with py2exe.

Comment: Yes I am refering to creating an exe out of the python project. My question is more about the Qt framework and not Python and PyQt as I know py2exe will take care of Python and PyQt. Would the client machine still need to have the Qt framework installed to run the exe?

Comment: I don't think you've really tested it out. Probably Qt 4 fooled you, because a Qt 4 app with missing plugins has the appearance of "working", when it's really broken. Make sure that whatever image format and database plugins that you need are in fact included. In my experience from a couple years ago, they definitely weren't included. You need to take [extra steps](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyQt) to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

Py2exe, when used with PyQt, will only copy the basics needed to get a Qt application to run. It won't copy the plugins that likely need. You [need to take extra steps](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyQt) to install whatever image, platform, phonon, multimedia, etc. plugins you may need.

By basics I mean it will install the *directly linked* libraries from the Qt framework. Qt consists of a bunch of libraries. Some of those are linked directly into any executable using them (like the PyQt library), some of them are plugins. Py2exe will *not* copy those plugins, since it generally has no way of knowing which ones you may need. You need to let Py2exe know about the plugins your application requires: [add them to the configuration file (setup.py)](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Py2exeAndPyQt).

Comment: yes, I agree, but the question is, if you need to INSTALL PyQt on the client PC and you do not. It can be handled from py2exe script.

Comment: Hi Kuba I think you might be understanding my question better. Yes I am asking if the client machine would need to have the Qt framework installed in order for the application to work when I create an exe using py2exe. I know that I would not need PyQt but that was never the issue. I am concerned that the client machine would need to install the Qt framework itself which is around 500mb from what I can see on their site.

Comment: @Twist What you see on the website is not just the framework, it's an entire development environment, with an IDE thrown in for a good measure. You do *not* want to distribute that!

Comment: Thank you very much Kuba. Will this mean that I need to install the Qt framework (smaller version not the one on the Qt website) on the client machine in a seperate step before they could use the exe created by py2exe?

Comment: @Twist No! I hope I was clear. Py2exe "will only copy the basics needed to get a Qt application to run". You still have to tell Py2exe, via setup.py, what other files to copy beyond the basic libraries (namely, the plugins). Besides, you can just test it for yourself: spin a VM with a pristine copy of Windows, run your py2exe'd application, and see for yourself.